# How to insert into specific row in database?

Tags: php, mysql, user-input

Okay, so my database is as follows by this order:

id (primary - auto_increment), username (unique), password, fname, mail

I have it so that users register a username and password and it adds it to the database, first of all. No username can be the same, and when it does add the data to the database it auto increments the ID. All of that works, but now I made an account settings page in which the user can change their email and first name, but it isn't working. I have the user enter variables in a form on one page, and it posts their first name as ufname (for update first name) and umail (for update mail). Then on the next page which updates the database I have this code:

```
session_start();
if(!isset($_SESSION['userId'])) {
die("&nbsp;You are not signed in. Please <a href='login.php'>click here</a> to sign in.");
} else {
$changeTXT = $_SESSION['username'];
$changeTXT = strtolower($changeTXT);
$changeTXT = ucfirst($changeTXT);
echo "Account Settings: <font color='red'>" . $changeTXT . "</font><br /><br />";

$ufname = $_POST['ufname'];
$umail = $_POST['umail'];

mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "sp1151") or die(mysql_error());


mysql_select_db("usersys") or die(mysql_error());

mysql_query("INSERT INTO userdb (id, username, password, fname, mail) VALUES('','','','$ufname', '$umail') ");


echo $umail . "<br /><br />";
echo $ufname;

}
```

Oh, I also have the users logged in on sessions too.

But how would I insert the first name and e-mail the user enters into their specific row on the database? My database name is userdb.

Comment: tell me you did no just disclose your mysql username and password in this post

Comment: Lol, its just a test on a local pc xD. Otherwise I wouldn't have.

Answer (score 17):

You need to run an UPDATE query to alter an existing row, not an INSERT.

```
$sql = "UPDATE userdb SET fname = '$ufname', mail = '$umail' WHERE id = $id";
mysql_query($sql);
```

Comment: Please parameterize this to protect against SQL injection.

Comment: Indeed; use mysql_real_escape_string or a prepared statement to protect against SQL injection!

Answer (score 8):

You need to do use and `UPDATE` statement instead of an `INSERT`:

```
UPDATE userdb SET fname = ?, mail = ? WHERE username = ?;
```

That aside you should seriously consider using prepared statements with query parameters to prevent SQL injection attacs.

Answer (score 1):

Try this `UPDATE` query:

```
Update 'tableName' set 'columnName' = 'newEntry' where 'rowID' = 'value'.
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using the SQL `UPDATE` query?

Comment: No, i'm rather new to it all. I am really trying to learn it the best I can. :) How shall I go about doing so?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
mysql_query("UPDATE userdb SET fname = '$ufname', umail = '$umail' WHERE id = '$_SESSION['userId']' ");
```

Comment: why the down vote? the other answers are using $id, which is not the right var, as he's got the id stored at $_SESSION['userId'].